# How to get a list of exceptions?

Tags: python, exception

What is the documented way to get a list of catcheable exceptions for an operation?

I want to avoid using the very, very bad construction

```
try:
    # an operation
except:
    # do stuff if anything goes wrong
```

but in order to do so I need to know what I can catch, and act accordingly.

I know that there is [a list of built-in exceptions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#bltin-exceptions) and that standard functions are usually documented with their exceptions but it does not help when using, for instance, APIs (as an example the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/) does not list exception, but the examples mysteriously use them). Is there a standard way to query exceptions together with (hopefully) their docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is read the documentation. There's no way to query it.

Consider the following simple function:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

What exceptions can it throw? The answer is **all of them**.

```
class ExceptionThrower(object):
    def __init__(self, exception):
        self.exception = exception
    def __add__(self, other):
        raise self.exception
```

`add(ExceptionThrower(AnyException), 3)` will throw any exception you provide. Without static types and explicit Java-style `throws` declarations, it's nearly impossible to tell what kinds of exceptions a function will throw. The best you can do is read the docs to see what it was designed to throw. Some documentation styles or function annotations might allow programmatic inspection of what exceptions a function is expected to throw, but there's nothing standard or required.

Comment: ...and even in Java, there are exception derived from `RuntimeException` not subject to exception checks. In general, checked exceptions seem to be falling out of favor in modern Java development, and its chief competitor DotNET [never had them](http://www.artima.com/intv/handcuffs.html).

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all exceptions, you can run:

```
exceptions = []
todo = set([Exception])
while todo:
    ex = todo.pop()
    exceptions.append(ex)
    todo.update(ex.__subclasses__())
```

But which exceptions are thrown you can only find out, by testing your function with illegal parameters.